# Using NSKeyedArchiver to generate XML from NSManagedObjects held in an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, nskeyedarchiver

I have an NSDictionary, which contains a bunch of NSManagedObjects. 
I can then use NSKeyedArchiver to write this to an NSData object.
These are generated using [this method.](https://gist.github.com/611157) Which works fine and allows me to save a section of schema to disc and then read it back as a new set of objects in the core data model.
If I use either  archivedDataWithRootObject:
or archiveRootObject:toFile:, as per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
I can see that the format of the archive is  NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0, whereas I want to serialise in NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0, so that I can write my objects to a file and then process them elsewhere as plain old XML. (In fact I want to generate documents from them on a Windows based system.)

1) Is there a way I can do this? If so how?
2) Is there a better approach.

I want to maintain the serialised nature, since I also want to send the file back to the iOS device later and recreate the object model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create your own instance of `NSKeyedArchiver` with `initForWritingWithMutableData:`.
2. Set the format with `setOutputFormat:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0`.
3. Encode your root object with `encodeObject:forKey:`.
4. Call `finishEncoding`.

To unarchive the data you encoded in this way, you have to similarly instantiate an `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ole! I was heading in that direction, but was not sure if it was the right way. Here is what I did in code in case it helps someone.

```
NSDictionary *dataAsDictionary=[self toDictionaryBlockingRelationships:blockRelationship];
NSString   *savePath = [@"~/Documents/Saved.data" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSMutableData *xmlData=[NSMutableData data];

NSKeyedArchiver *archive=[[NSKeyedArchiver alloc ]initForWritingWithMutableData:xmlData];

[archive setOutputFormat:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0];
[archive encodeRootObject:dataAsDictionary];
[archive finishEncoding];

if(![xmlData writeToFile:savePath atomically:NO]){
    NSLog(@"Failed to write to file to filePath=%@", savePath);
}
[archive release];
```